# How can I prevent certain tracks from going to iPod?

Tags: itunes, ipod

I manually put music onto my iPod by dragging albums over from the library in iTunes.  For some albums, I don't want all of the tracks to copy over to the iPod - for example, audio commentaries and dialog tracks.  Short of deleting these tracks from my iTunes library, how can I prevent specific tracks from being copied over to the iPod when I place albums?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I love the setting where you can only sync songs with the checkbox to one or more iOS devices.

[image: iTunes - Sync only checked songs and video]

Simple deselect the songs by plalist, genre, or as you find them and even if they are in a playlist or genius mix that would normally install the song on your device during a sync, iTunes will suppress those songs that are not check marked.

Comment: What did you use to draw that awesome arrow?

Comment: Skitch - it's on the App Store - free

Comment: Ah, that's what it is.

Comment: Hmmm - this option is greyed out for me.  Perhaps because I don't don't have "Sync Music" selected?  (I just drag over stuff that I want.)

Comment: That's a great observation. I've honestly never tried that. You can have both sync music ( but select no playlists to sync ) and still retain your preferred method. Feel free to edit my answer to cover this case if you find it may help others.

Comment: I apologize if I'm being dense, but how can I have both 'sync music' and 'dragging stuff over' working?

Comment: First you turn on sync, then you drag songs and playlists to the device with the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

bmike's answer is correct; alternatively, you could select the album and hold <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> while clicking the tracks you don't wish to copy. Then, drag the still-selected ones to the iPod.

Comment: Nice bonus answer! I always forget about manually adding and this is a nice combination of selection tools and drag/drop.